# Nullptr in ternary operator

Tags: c++

Consider:

```
struct A { bool operator==(const A& that) { return true; } };
boost::optional<A&> f()
{
    std::vector<A> vec;
    auto it = std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), A());

    // Version A
    return (it == vec.end() ? nullptr : *it);

    // Version B
    if (it == vec.end()) {
        return nullptr;
    } else {
        return *it;
    }
}
```

Why does version A not compile (error C2446: ':' : no conversion from 'A' to 'nullptr') while version B does?

(I know that I can do e.g.

```
return (it == vec.end() ? boost::optional<A&>() : *it);
```

, my question is: why is construction from nullptr apparently treated differently from with the ternary operator?)

Only tested on msvc12 (=Visual Studio 2013).

Comment: Actually [none of the `boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/optional/doc/html/optional/reference/header__boost_optional_optional_hpp_.html#boost_optional.reference.header__boost_optional_optional_hpp_.header_optional_optional) constructors takes a `nullptr`, try with `none_t`.

Comment: I know, and yet my 'Version B' compiles - my question is: why?

Comment: Even when you get it to "work", it doesn't work. Returning a (possible) reference to an entry in a local array? Won't work very well indeed. Also, a reference to a non-pointer object can never be a null pointer.

Comment: Well, a terneray operator result need to have the same exeactly same type for both result parts. `nullptr` has a different type than `*it`.

Comment: @Joachim Yes I know that too, this is a minimal sample to demonstrate. Feel free to make it static if you want something that will run. In my real code my container is a member of a class. Re: your second point, the optional is either empty or contains an A&. Unless I'm misunderstanding your point and there is something I'm missing wrt references in an optional.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rules for ternary operator from standard 5.16

> if the second and third operand have different types and either has
> (possibly cv-qualified) class type, or if both are glvalues of the
> same value category and the same type except for cv-qualification, an
> attempt is made to convert each of those operands to the type of the
> other.
>
> ...
>
> Otherwise (if E1 or E2 has a non-class type, or if they both have
> class types but the underlying classes are not the same and neither is
> a base class of the other): E1 can be converted to match E2 if E1 can
> be implicitly converted to the type that E2 would have after applying
> the lvalue-to- rvalue (4.1), array-to-pointer (4.2), and
> function-to-pointer (4.3) standard conversions.

`A` is not implicitly convertible to `nullptr` and `nullptr` is not implicitly convertible to `A`.

Second version is compiled, since there is some implicit conversion from `nullptr` to `optional`.

Comment: Right, after your first edit it made sense, when I add a A(void*) {} constructor, it does compile (not going to do that though, don't worry). Thanks.